# Unable to get property 'customXmlParts' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, office365, word-web-addins

I am working on executing a function on a custom ribbon bar button click from a Word365 web add-in.
As this process involves multiple dialogs, I am using the action type '`ExecuteFunction`' in the manifest file for the ribbon bar button click.

Upon the ribbon bar button 'Workflow' click, the 'Attach' dialog box should open. there's a button named 'Attach' in that dialog. It should open a server browsing dialog, and selected server file will return a json, I need to convert it to xml and store within the `document.CustomXmlParts`, as it should be saved as a document specific value.

I have not started on the server browsing part yet. I am trying to store some sample xml within the `document.CustomXmlParts` as a test try. But I am unable to access the `Office.context.document.CustomXmlParts`, it gives error "`Unable to get property 'customXmlParts' of undefined or null reference`". But when I try to access `Office.context.document.CustomXmlParts` within the FunctionFile.js, I can save the xml content and retrieve it successfully.

Please help me with figure out what is actually wrong.

**Manifest file**

```
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.AttachXML">                     
<Label resid="Contoso.FuntionAttachXML.Label" />
       <Supertip>
            <Title resid="Contoso.FuntionAttachXML.Label" />
            <Description resid="Contoso.FuntionAttachXML.Tooltip" />
       </Supertip>
       <Icon>
            <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
            <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
            <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
       </Icon>
       <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
            <FunctionName>ShowAttachXMLDialog</FunctionName>
       </Action>
 </Control>
```

**FunctionFile.js**

```
// The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded.
(function () {
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        // If you need to initialize something you can do so here.
    };
})();

var ShowAttachXMLDialog = function (event) {
    try {
        var dialogUrl = 'https://' + location.host + '/App/Dialogs/DlgAttach/DlgAttachXML.html';

        Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(dialogUrl, { width: 60, height: 50, requireHTTPS: true }, function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        

    showAlert('editDlg', asyncResult.error.message);
        } else {
            _dialog = asyncResult.value;
        }
    });

    } catch (e) {
        showAlert(e.location, e.message);
    }

}
```

**DlgAttachXML.js file**

```
(function () {

    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        // If you need to initialize something you can do so here.
        var doc = Office.context.document;

        $(document).ready(function () {

            thisDocument = document;
            document.getElementById("attach-button").onclick = selectXMLFromServer;
        });
    };

})();

var selectXMLFromServer = function (event) {
    //that sample xml I am trying to insert.
    var xmlString = "<Reviewers xmlns='http://schemas.contoso.com/review/1.0'><Reviewer>Juan</Reviewer><Reviewer>Hong</Reviewer><Reviewer>Sally</Reviewer></Reviewers>";

    //Error occurs in here
    Office.context.document.customXmlParts.addAsync(xmlString,
        (asyncResult) => {
            Office.context.document.settings.set('AttachedXML', asyncResult.value.id);
            Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();
        }
    );
    event.completed();
}
```

Thank you in advance.